# How do multiple on statements work in a single inner join?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

There are two ON clauses one after another, like so:

```
select * from foo
left join b on b.ID = foo.pID
left join c
inner join foo as f
ON b.ID = f.pProject
ON c.Name = f.Hostname
```

Does it mean that all 3 tables are being joined together?

Answer (score 4):

It means that the joins are nested such that the inner join between f and b happens before they are collectively outer joined to c.  However I think you may have some lines transposed.  This could be rewritten with some indentation and parenthesis to *maybe* make it clearer.

```
select *
  from foo 
  left join b
    on b.ID = foo.pID
  left join (c
       join foo as f
         ON c.Name = f.Hostname
       )
    ON b.ID = f.pProject
```

You can think of it like the JOIN key word acts as an open parenthesis and the ON key word acts as a closing parenthesis in nested matching pairs.  The order of precedence or scoping on this is such that the nested joins can't access the the enclosing joins until the nested joins have been completed.  As such your final two ON statements as written would likely throw an error until they are transposed as I did above.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. 
However, the code I posted did not throw an error. It is part of a larger query that executes without any errors.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're not getting an error with your original code. When I build out some sample tables in SQL Server over at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8de5a/5) and run your query against it, I get the following error: `The mulit-part identifier "b.ID" could not be bound` as expected since b is currently out of scope, however, after switching the last two lines it runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from foo
left  join b 
        on b.ID = foo.pID
left  join c
inner join foo as f
        ON f.pProject = b.ID  
        ON c.Name = f.Hostname
```

I have seen this used before but not in this same way.  I forget the purpose but I know it had a good use.

In this case I think it joins on `f.pProject = b.ID` first so it can get the value for `f.Hostname`.